# Issue modifying map from goroutine func

Tags: multithreading, pointers, go, maps, goroutine

```
scores := make(map[string]int)
percentage := make(map[string]float64)
total := 0

for i, ans := range answers {
    answers[i] = strings.ToLower(ans)
}

wg := sync.WaitGroup{}

go func() {
    wg.Add(1)

    body, _ := google(question)

    for _, ans := range answers {
        count := strings.Count(body, ans)
        total += count
        scores[ans] += 5 // <------------------- This doesn't work
    }

    wg.Done()
}()
```

Here's a snippet of code, my issue is, that I am unable to modify the scores, I've tried using pointers, I've tried doing it normally, I've tried passing it as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Package sync](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/)
>
> import "sync"
>
> [type WaitGroup](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup)
>
> A WaitGroup waits for a collection of goroutines to finish. The main
>   goroutine calls Add to set the number of goroutines to wait for. Then
>   each of the goroutines runs and calls Done when finished. At the same
>   time, Wait can be used to block until all goroutines have finished.

---

You have provided us with a non-working fragment of code. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

As a guess, your use of a `sync.WaitGroup` looks strange. For example, by simply following the instructions in the sync.Waitgroup documentation, I would expect something more like the following:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

func google(string) (string, error) { return "yes", nil }

func main() {
    question := "question?"
    answers := []string{"yes", "no"}

    scores := make(map[string]int)
    total := 0

    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()

        body, _ := google(question)
        for _, ans := range answers {
            count := strings.Count(body, ans)
            total += count
            scores[ans] += 5 // <-- This does work
        }
    }()
    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println(scores, total)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/sZmB2Dc5RjL

Output:

```
map[yes:5 no:5] 1
```

Comment: Oh I see, what a noob mistake, I've even done this in the past, should've ran with the race argument, thank you ever so much :)

Sorry about the code snippet, it was late at night and my first time using StackOverflow, I'll make sure to provide fully working code next time not a random snippet without context.